# Can't get images to show up, trying to display 5 random cards from directory file

Tags: javafx

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My pane opens, but it is blank. I have the file (card) as a directory (image) in the src folder. I have tried writing this so many different way but always get the same result. I just need to make the images actually show up. I don't know how to get the card images to show up. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package Assignment;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Assignment extends Application {
    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Initialize card deck
        ArrayList<Integer> cards = getCards();

        // Create a FlowPane
        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();
        pane.setVgap(10);
        pane.setHgap(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15));

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(new Image("file:image/card/" + cards.get(i) + ".png")));
        }

        // Create scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,500, 300);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Poker 1");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> getCards() {
        ArrayList<Integer> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            cards.add(i + 1);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(cards);
        return cards;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What directory are your cards images in?

Click 'edit configuration' on the run button drop down menu, then look at the "Working directory" entry. Ex. Mine was C:\Users\NAME\IdeaProjects\Test

Placing the cards in C:\Users\NAME\IdeaProjects\Test\image\cards[1-52].png made your code work for me as written.

Comment: Moving the images out of the src folder and into just the project folder worked. Thank you so much!